# Black spots on the model

Tags: modeling, mesh, unreal-engine

At the modeling step, I've taken an issue with my model. Around the deleted parts of UV sphere appeared a lot of black spots, which I also have taken with imported model in Unreal Engine 4.

Its looks like this:

[image: like this]

And with enabled "Mesh analysis" (Distortion, with angles between 1 and 0 degrees)

[image]

How can I fix this issue? Or maybe it's a trouble of Blender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this affect when using "smooth" shading on the model. Changing from Smooth to flat will probably fix this, but then your model also look - well - flat. You might want to subdivide your faces around the area a bit more, which should allow for a smoother shading (toggle back & forth between smooth & flat in Object mode to refresh the shading).

Comment: After few hours working with this model I can said, that subdivision solve this issue partly. But using "Bevel tool" at the edges for my model (around the entrance) helps me to make smoothed model more beautiful and refined.